# Access floats of CXMMatrix - () operator not working

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I'm trying to use updated codes of "Frank Luna" book on directX11 where I using VS2017 with WindowsSDK10. I've read some notes about migration from Frank and did eveything he said in the link below :
http://www.d3dcoder.net/Data/Book4/d3d11Win10.htm

but got stuck here . I know there was same question from @poncho and answered well : 
[Access floats of XMMatrix - () operator not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475929/access-floats-of-xmmatrix-operator-not-working/26459089)

But I have trouble with type CXMMATRIX instead of XMMATRIX and I couldn't get result with the solution provided for him.

So I have to access the rows and columns of an CXMMATRIX :

```
void ExtractFrustumPlanes(XMFLOAT4 planes[6], CXMMATRIX M)
{
    //
    // Left
    //
    planes[0].x = M(0,3) + M(0,0);
    planes[0].y = M(1,3) + M(1,0);
    planes[0].z = M(2,3) + M(2,0);
    planes[0].w = M(3,3) + M(3,0);
...
```

But I get :

> call of an object of a class type without appropriate operator() or
>   conversion functions to pointer-to-function type

and

> term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments

It points to argument M of type CXMMATRIX where defined as below in DirectXMath.h :

```
// Fix-up for (2nd+) XMMATRIX parameters to pass by reference
typedef const XMMATRIX& CXMMATRIX;
```

What's all these errors about !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frank Luna's book is overall a great introduction to the Direct 11 API, but unfortunately suffers from heavily utilizing the legacy DirectX SDK which is deprecated per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx). One of those aspects is that he's actually using the xnamath library (a.k.a. xboxmath version 2) instead of the DirectXMath library (a.k.a. xboxmath version 3)

See [Book Recommendations](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2014/04/07/book-recommendations/) and [Introducing DirectXMath](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/03/26/introducing-directxmath/)

I made a number of changes when reworking the library as DirectXMath. First, the types are actually in C++ namespaces instead of the global namespace. In your headers, you should use full name specification:

```
#include <DirectXMath.h>

void MyFunction(..., DirectX::CXMMATRIX M);
```

In your cpp source files you should use:

```
#include <DirectXMath.h>

using namespace DirectX;
```

Another change was to strongly discourage the use of 'per-element' access on the `XMVECTOR` and `XMMATRIX` data types. As discussed in the [DirectXMath Programmers Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418725.aspx#type_usage_guidelines_), these types are by design proxies for the SIMD register types which cannot be directly accessed by-element. Instead, you covert to the `XMFLOAT4X4` representation which allows per-element access because that's a scalar structure.

You can see this by the fact that the operators you are trying to use are only defined for 'no-intrinsics' mode (i.e. when using scalar instead of SIMD operations like SSE, ARM-NEON, etc.):

```
#ifdef _XM_NO_INTRINSICS_
    float operator() (size_t Row, size_t Column) const { return m[Row][Column]; }
    float& operator() (size_t Row, size_t Column) { return m[Row][Column]; }
#endif
```

Again, by design, this process is a bit 'verbose' because it lets you know it's not free. Some people find this aspect of DirectXMath a little frustrating to use especially when they are first getting started. In that case, I recommend you take a look at the [SimpleMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SimpleMath) wrapper in the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki). You can use the types `Vector3`, `Vector4`, `Matrix`, etc. and they freely convert (through C++ operators and constructors) as needed to `XMVECTOR` and `XMMATRIX`. It's not nearly as efficient, but it's a lot more forgiving to use.

The particular function you wrote is also a bit problematic. First, it's a little odd to mix `XMFLOAT4` and `XMMATRIX` parameters. For 'in-register, SIMD-friendly' calling convention, you'd use:

```
void XM_CALLCONV ExtractFrustumPlanes(XMVECTOR planes[6], FXMMATRIX M)
```

For details on why, see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418728.aspx#Call_Conventions).

If you want to just entirely scalar math, use either the non-SIMD types:

```
void ExtractFrustumPlanes(XMFLOAT4 planes[6], const XMFLOAT4X4& M)
```

or better yet use SimpleMath so you can avoid having to write explicit conversions to/from `XMVECTOR` or `XMMATRIX`

```
using DirectX::SimpleMath;

void ExtractFrustumPlanes(Vector4 planes[6], const Matrix& M)
```

> Note that the latest version of DirectXMath is on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMath/releases), [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/directxmath/), and [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/ports/directxmath/).

Comment: well , I preferred non-SIMD types. much more than what you said is heavy and complex. Anyway, although as a beginner I can not understand it, but my problem was resolved with your help.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Definitely check out SimpleMath. If you don't want to use any other part of the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki), you can just download the [SimpleMath.h](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/master/Inc/SimpleMath.h), [SimpleMath.inl](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/master/Inc/SimpleMath.inl), and [SimpleMath.cpp](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/master/Src/SimpleMath.cpp) files to add to your project. You will need to edit the includes for ``SimpleMath.cpp`` to match your project. It needs ``<d3d11.h>`` and ``<algorithm>``.